# Duplicate bean names

Tags: java, spring

I have two beans with the same name in different packages:

```
package A;

class EMDao {}

package B;

class EMDao {}

package C;

import B.EMDao;
class EMService { @Resource EMDao emDao; }
```

I get this exception:

> org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException:
>   Annotation-specified bean name for bean class EMDao conflicts with
>   existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class
>   B.EMDao.

Now I am trying to do this:

```
package B;

@Qualifier(value="bEMDao")
class EMDao {}

package C;

import B.EMDao;
class EMService { @Qualifier(value="bEMDao") @Resource EMDao emDao; }
```

But I am still getting the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What about? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015205/2-beans-with-same-but-different-package-how-to-autowire

Comment: How are you defining and instantiating these beans?  XML or annotations?

Comment: BrunoDM's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you will get the same error because you specify the same values for bean names: `value="bEMDao"`. The bean names should differ, e.g. `value="bEMDao"`